# can anyone help me with the trigger insert problem i created?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

so I made a trigger insert like this:

```
create or replace trigger discount
after insert on transaction
for each row
begin
if (new.desc_date = 'Y') then
insert into desc_transaction(discount) values (new.discount = '0.1');
end if;
end;
/
```

> Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

```
show error;
3/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
3/54     PL/SQL: ORA-00917: missing comma
```

how to solve it.

data :
desc_date contains only yes and no because if November is discounted and October is not.
For the discount section contains 0.1 and null so if desc_date is yes then 0.1 otherwise it will be null or ' '.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong syntax. Should've been

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER discount
   AFTER INSERT
   ON transaction
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF :new.desc_date = 'Y'
   THEN
      INSERT INTO desc_transaction (discount)
           VALUES (0.1);
   END IF;
END;
/
```

---

Or, possibly even better,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER discount
   AFTER INSERT
   ON transaction
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO desc_transaction (discount)
        VALUES (CASE WHEN :new.desc_date = 'Y' THEN 0.1 ELSE NULL END);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your `insert` statement is incorrect. Try the following:

```sql
insert into desc_transaction(discount) values ('0.1');
```

Side note - `discount` probably isn't a `varchar` column. If this guess is correct, you should be using a numeral literal (`0.1`) and not a string literal (`'0.1'`) like you currently have.